# How to remove quotes from start and end of the string at a specific line in python?

Tags: python, string, replace, quotes

I have to replace a string in a file at specific line and it should not have quotes at start and end of the string when it be replaced.

I have to read the contents from file1 and replace it in file2 at specific line.

**file1.txt:**

```
File1Content - "Replace this line in file"
```

**file2.tf:**

```
var head{
default = File2Content - "This is file2."
}
var tail{
default = "$$Replace Here$$"
}
```

**Python:**

```
with open('file1.txt') as fd:
    file1_text = fd.read()
with open('file2.txt') as fw:
    file2_text = fw.read()
with open('file3.tf' , 'w') as fz:
    fz.write(file2_text.replace("$$Replace Here$$",rep_string))
```

**Expected Output:**

```
var head{
default = File2Content - "This is file2."
}
var tail{
default = File1Content - "Replace this line in file"
}
```

But What i'm getting is.

**Output:**

```
var head{
default = File2Content - "This is file2."
}
var tail{
default = "File1Content - "Replace this line in file""
}
```

I need tail block as **default = File1Content - "Replace this line in file"**
I don't want that quotes at the start and end of the string in tail block. Any idea to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

try replacing this line:

```
with open('file3.tf' , 'w') as fz:
    ind.write(file2_text.replace("$$Replace Here$$",rep_string))
```

with this:

```
with open('file3.tf' , 'w') as fz:
    ind.write(file2_text.replace('"$$Replace Here$$"',rep_string))
```

Comment: Both codes look similar.

Comment: I added single quotes before the double quotes

Comment: that's because the code is not replacing the double quotes from the second tf file

Comment: If i replace it with single quotes, string replacement is not happening in the file.

Comment: dont replace, add both.
try copying and pasting the line from here

Answer (score 0):

The template file already contains the quotes:

```
var head{
default = File2Content - "This is file2."
}
var tail{
default = "$$Replace Here$$"
}
```

If you don't want them, remove them:

```
var head{
default = File2Content - "This is file2."
}
var tail{
default = $$Replace Here$$
}
```